# Canonical flaps

Tags: english, phonetics

Dear colleagues: I have a question about canonical flaps. The literature is not clear on whether a canonical flap has a burst or not. I have found in my data that many flaps do have a burst (sometimes multiple bursts). Would these be a canonical form of flap?